# Make notifications response when the job is completed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, beanstalkd

I am using Symfony framework3 with Pheanstalk bundle and Doctrine. I creating the event which sends data to beanstalk. The other SF app on the different server perform a job and update notification status on the first SF app to completed. How can I check when the status is updated and than set alert like that:

http://byrobin.nl/store/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2016/03/local.png

I can create a command that have infinitive loop and checking for status update, maybe listener on preUpdate? Also I have the same problem with running command that checking and executing beanstalk jobs. In dev mode i run it by hand, but i try infinitive loop like while(true) but it load my buffer and crash. I was thinking of cron job that runs every minute or two? What is best solution for this two problems? Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It would be good with WebSockets as that doesn't involve while(true) loop. A websocket can be opened by the frontend after a task has been submitted for processing. After the job finished processing it would notify the server side of the websocket to relay the info back on the socket for the frontend.

2) Another option is to submit a message, and in the params name anonymous tube (make a unique name based on time and some prefix) where the worker needs to put the answer. And before submitting the job you subscribe on beanstalkd to the anonymous channel, then submit the job, and the job finishes it will post the answer to the tube. Since there is already a subscriber there it will reserve the job and deal with it, then delete it, and the tube gets removed too.